# Can you define a spinor in relation to a mesh?

Tags: geometry, spinors

Taking a mesh of points which approximates a manifold $M$,

one can define a vector field at each point by assigning each point A to another point B, which creates a vector AB.

Similarly one can define a tensor at each point by assigning several points to each point.

One could probably also define a scalar field in the same way as the vector field but taking the magnitude of the vectors.

These constructions are invariant under rotations of the surface.

If one wanted to define a spinor wave function $\psi^\alpha(x)$ on the surface, there does not seem to be a geometric construction in terms of tuples of points or anything else. Even though two of these objects can form a vector which can be described as so. $\overline{\psi}\gamma_\mu \psi$.

**Is there any known way to include spinors in a geometric construction?**

The only way I can think of is perhaps to have a stack of manifolds $M^\alpha$ which is kind of like a fibration and during a rotation this stack changes its order in some way that it gets back to it's original order in 720 degree rotation. But not entirely sure how this would work, or how two spinors would combine to be a vector. A spinor would be a collection of points from several layers of this stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you probably want is to go to a Vierbein formulation and then describe the spinors as fields transforming according to the desired representation of the local Lorentz group. I so far as I'm aware, Lorentz principle bundle constructions are the only real way to get at spinnors geometrically, which is why such formulations are necessary if we wanted to couple a spinnor to gravity in a diffeomorphism invariant manner.